# how can i get to know which app package is startig my activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-package-managers

there are many applications which invokes my application in system> I want to know which app invoked my app or activity or service presently ?

Can anybody help me to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide different activities to start your app, each being called by different apps. Or you can monitor user actions after app launch (navigation to screens etc) and determine which application may have launched your app. These two are relatively logical but apart from this you can monitor and look for currently running apps (look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091350/how-to-find-the-currently-running-applications-programatically-in-android) for one possible way to do that) and then maybe determine which application launched your app.

Note that these are just strategies, not a definite answer.

Comment: !st two options i can't, coz i cant write all other apps. and for 3rd options does that shows in any order or its random app list? because i want last running app

Comment: Random I think but the other answer by KunalK seems to be better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

In the starting activity of your application you can try following code to get the **PackageName** of the app that invokes your application.

```
if(getIntent().getPackage()!=null){
   String packageName = getIntent().getPackage();
}
```

Comment: here in my case its android softkeyboard, is that possible here ?

Comment: i am not sure, but you can give it a try. :)