# How to load all running tasks to a ListView layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I'm trying to load all running tasks to a list view in Android, I done it for all installed applications, but I don't know how to get it for running tasks.

I' could display the running tasks on toast message, but don't know how to get that on ListView. Please help me.

Comment: yes, this answer showing how to get running tasks package name, but I need to know how to load that in a ListView layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you'll first want to get a list of the currently running tasks. You can do so with the following code:

```
final   ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
final List<RunningTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    for (int i = 0; i < recentTasks.size(); i++) 
    {
        Log.d("Executed app", "Application executed : " +recentTasks.get(i).baseActivity.toShortString()+ "\t\t ID: "+recentTasks.get(i).id+"");         
    }
```

Source: [How to find the currently running applications programatically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091350/how-to-find-the-currently-running-applications-programatically-in-android)

Then once you have the list of current tasks, you'll want to create an Adapter, which will populate your list view. There are two main ways you could do this:

- Use a standard ArrayAdapter and pass in a list of Strings. You would have to generate this list of Strings from the list of tasks that were returned to you. This is a great way to display only a single line of text for each task per list element.
- Extend the standard ArrayAdapter to accept a list of Tasks (RunningTaskInfo) and resolve the content inside the ArrayAdapter subclass. This is necessary if you want to display more than a single line of text for each task per list element, for example, the task ID or an image.

Both examples are explained well in the following tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listview_listviewexample

Finally, you will want to associate your Adapter to your ListView by calling:

```
listViewReference.setAdapter(yourAdapterReference);
```

Your ListView will then be populated automatically by your adapter.

Comment: No problem, all the best with your project :)