# Get application package name that currently showing activity

Tags: android-activity, android

By using [activityManager.getRunningTasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091350/how-to-find-the-currently-running-applications-programatically-in-android) you can get the current running applications in android.
How ever it does not tell you which of those tasks `activity` is showing right now.

How do I get this information?

Answer (score 1):

To get topmost activity you will need to interrogate the first task returned by getRunningTasks:

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
RunningTaskInfo info = activityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0);
ComponentName topActivity = info.topActivity.getClassName();
```

BTW, the word is that getRunningTasks will be deprecated in Android L, so keep in mind.