# Is it possible to get info and overlay another app from my app?

Tags: android, mobile

Hi I am new to this topic so maybe this is noob question but I couldn't find anything relevant on the web so I am asking here.
I want to make application that adds some more interesting rich information into another app not related to my app.

That is, imagine that my app would overlay some sports betting app from one betting company with odds from companies around the world and compare them with original data in app which i can get(?)

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. First of all you could use [StandOut](https://github.com/pingpongboss/StandOut) library to overlay any app you want. And second thing you could use is info about [running apps on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091350/how-to-find-the-currently-running-applications-programatically-in-android).

You cannot access information of running app directly. But still you have some hack to access other [app resources](https://github.com/stepango/DownloadableThemes/blob/master/src/com/example/DownloadableThemes/MyActivity.java) via creating context of other app installed on your device. Maybe this information will help.

Comment: First part is definitely useful this is actualy what i was looking for. For the second part one more question. Is it possible to lets say inspcet color of concrete pixel in app i want to overlay ?

Comment: @Ziker unfortunately no, there are no way(without root) to get any graphics  data displayed on screen, that's why you need to find another way to do it

Comment: Ok  i will search for some workarounds anyway thanks