# Custom Keyboard | How to know which application is using my input method

Tags: android

I'm developing an input method, but i need to know which application is using my input method.

**For example (as image):**

- if someone other open my keyboard for Telegram, the keyboard will turn color to lightblue.
- if someone open my keyboard to write on WhatsApp, the keyboard will turn color to green.
  [image]

There is a way to get the package?

Comment: I'm developing a custom keyboard that fits the "caller" application

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091350/how-to-find-the-currently-running-applications-programatically-in-android you can check what is running programmatically in Android. Sorry for the confusing response earlier, still waking up :P

Comment: Maybe it's too late, but I think this could help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35811641/how-to-detect-which-app-is-opened-on-android