# How to detect which app is opened on android

Tags: android, keyboard

I am developing an android custom keyboard and i want to send stickies to my friends for example on hangouts from my keyboard. I added some png for this.

When I use the android's share api I have to select first an app to share with. Is it possible to detect the current opened application from my keyboard? For example if I am chatting with hangouts then I want to call the intent telling it to share with "com.something.hangouts"

If I am in FB messenger then telling it "com.something.facebook.messenger" etc...

I tried to get it like this:

```
fun getOpenedApplication() {
    var am = this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager;

    var l = am.getRecentTasks(1,
            ActivityManager.RECENT_WITH_EXCLUDED);
    var i = l.iterator();

    var pm = this.packageManager;

    while (i.hasNext()) {
        try {
            var intent = i.next().baseIntent;
            var list = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent,
                    PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

            var c = pm.getApplicationLabel(pm.getApplicationInfo(
                    list[0].activityInfo.packageName,
                    PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));

            Toast.makeText(this, "Application name: " + c.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Application name not found: " + e.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

But it is not working well... It gives back the launcher or the keyboard. (randomly)

I tried to get the first app from Recent Apps list but it wasn't working

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's very easy task.

```
String packageName = getCurrentInputEditorInfo().packageName;
```

method of your InputMethodService class.

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution!

Comment: Fantastic. Had to go through many threads on SO to get to this. kudos!

Comment: Thanks, Awesome Help from your side.

Comment: After hours of searching through many threads, this is the one line that I need exactly! Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

For Android L and above, use :

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) newContext.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<RunningAppProcessInfo> runAppProcessesList = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
for (RunningAppProcessInfo runAppProcess : runAppProcessesList) {
    if (runAppProcess.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
        Log.d("current foreground App", runAppProcess.processName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To get the current running application use the following function for android version till kitkat

```
public String getRunningAppPackageName()
{
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(1);
    RunningTaskInfo p = (RunningTaskInfo) tasks.get(0);

    return p.baseActivity.getPackageName();}
```

To get the current running application use the following function for android version above kitkat

```
     public String getRunningAppPackageName()
{
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();


    return activityManager.getRunnningAppProcesses().get(0).processName;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Accessibility Services but for that you need to redirect your users to the Accessibility Settings to turn it on. Sample code is below to get the package of the app which has been just opened .

```
 public class MyAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {

@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
         String packageName = event.getPackageName();
         if(packageName.equals("com.sample"))
            //Do whatever you want  
    }}
```

You can read more about it here [Accessibility Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use getRunningAppProcesses api from activitymanager but when your result will be more than 1MB (Basically in case when more than 30-35 apps are running) you will end up with 'TransactionTooLargeException' . This is android implementation not able to transfer the binder data more than 1 MB.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code

```
 /**
     * @param context
     * @return
     * @throws PackageManager.NameNotFoundException
     */
    public String getRunningPackageName(Context context) throws PackageManager.NameNotFoundException {
        ActivityManager mgr = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        String packagename = "";
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            List<ActivityManager.AppTask> tasks = mgr.getAppTasks();
            for (ActivityManager.AppTask task : tasks) {
                packagename = task.getTaskInfo().baseIntent.getComponent().getPackageName();
                if (packagename.equalsIgnoreCase(context.getPackageName().toString())) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> alltasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(1);
            packagename = alltasks.get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
        }
        return packagename;
    }


    private void yourMethodName(Context context, Bundle notifyBundle)  { 
            boolean isActivityFound = false;
            String packageName = "";
            try {
                packageName = getRunningPackageName(context);
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
     if (packageName.equalsIgnoreCase(context.getPackageName().toString())) {
            isActivityFound = true;
        }
    }
```