# In Andorid how can I switch to another process programatically?

Tags: android, process, switching

Given that I have the process id of another independent process or application, how can I switch to it and give it the focus from my application?

I can't seem to find a reference to this but I know it can be done as an app named OS Monitor allows me to do it as do other apps.

Regards,
Jim

Comment: What do you mean by "switch to".  You can start another application by firing an intent at it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing, how I took it is that you want to switch views to another page
The following code will load a GUI into an Intent (Put this in your MainActivity.java):

`Intent yourIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);`

This will have the Intent run:

`startActivity(yourIntent);`

If this isn't what you meant, please clarify your question :)

Comment: In Application A I want to relinquish control and switch the control/focus to Application B given that I have the PID for Application B.  The Android app "OS Monitor" allows the user t do this with a button on the process list.  Note both Applications are active and they are unrelated

Comment: oh okay i understand now. i'll work on the answer when i get home :)

Comment: okay I think I found what you're looking for [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091350/how-to-find-the-currently-running-applications-programatically-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

*Call any method which contains any process which you want to implement.*

Otherwise, clarify your question.