# How to detect 3rd party mirroring app is running in background while open my APK

Tags: android, kotlin

How can I address an issue where 3rd party applications such as AnyDesk or TeamViewer detect the secondary display as a mirroring app during testing of a project involving primary and secondary displays?

I used this code to check the secondary display:

```
fun getSecondaryDisplay(context: Context): Display? {
   val displayManager = context.getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE) as DisplayManager
   return displayManager.displays.find { it.displayId != Display.DEFAULT_DISPLAY }
}
```

How can I detect the 3rd party applications such as AnyDesk or TeamViewer is running in background.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the currently running applications programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091350/how-to-find-the-currently-running-applications-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: Maveňツ, No. Suggested link differs from my issue. I want to detect any 3rd party mirroring app is running or capturing my screen.