# Any way to check if a running process is a system process in android

Tags: android, process

I am building an android app in which I  need to show the list of currently running apps but It contain all the process including many system or defualt process  of android like : launcher,dailer etc.

Now is there any way to check if the currently running process is  not a system process (default process) of android.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please check my post and if it is correct, please mark it as a correct answer. Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per this [documentation](http://hi-android.info/doc/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo.html), it seems you can use FLAG_SYSTEM_PROCESS to identify a process is System process or not.  Here is SO discussion on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274874/see-android-recent-task-executed-by-the-user).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I think FLAG_SYSTEM_PROCESS is for the RunningService not for RunningProcess . I need to check for Currently RunningProcess.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my code:
First to get a list of running Apps do the following

```
public void RunningApps() {
        final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        //Get the Activity Manager Object
        ActivityManager aManager = 
        (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        //Get the list of running Applications
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> rapInfoList = 
                          aManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        //Iterate all running apps to get their details
        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo rapInfo : rapInfoList) {
            //error getting package name for this process so move on
            if (rapInfo.pkgList.length == 0)
                continue; 

            try {
                PackageInfo pkgInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(rapInfo.pkgList[0],
                PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);

                if (isSystemPackage(pkgInfo)) {
                    //do something here
                } 
                else {
                    //do something here
                }

            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d(TAG, "NameNotFoundException :" + rapInfo.pkgList[0]);
            }
        }
    }
```

The actual function to check if the running application is system app, and used in the previous method is given below

```
 /**
     * Return whether the given PackgeInfo represents a system package or not.
     * User-installed packages (Market or otherwise) should not be denoted as
     * system packages.
     *
     * @param pkgInfo The Package info object
     * @return Boolean value indicating if the application is system app
     */
    private boolean isSystemPackage(PackageInfo pkgInfo) {
        return (pkgInfo.applicationInfo.flags & 
                ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0;
    }
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: This is not returning running system process
`val rapInfoList = aManager.runningAppProcesses`
This returns only app processes. Do you know how to get running system process list?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ActivtyManager to get list of all running process in android.See the below link for more information [Android process killer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720164/android-process-killer) .

Comment: this is not what I want . I already have the list of running process but I want to check is  if any one them is a system process of android ...

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isAppRunning(Context context, String packageName) {
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> list = am.getRunningTasks(100);
    if (list.size() <= 0) {
      return false;
    }
    for (ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo info : list) {
      if (info.baseActivity.getPackageName().equals(packageName)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
}
```