# Android home screen lifecycle

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, android-launcher

Can someone explain me the "standard" Android home screens lifecycle?
I'm asking this because I've noticed that my home screen when it's started goes in create-pause-resume-destroy-create without a coherent logic (this could not be the right sequence, by the way it's always a mess). I was expecting it to be handled like all the other "normal" activities.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377429/what-exactly-androids-home-button-doing

Answer (score 0):

If it is an Android activity, it should follow the activity life cycle described [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle). Now it maay be possible to make it work differently (I don't know, never had to do that) but it is going against Android development guidelines and in many ways may not be maintainable, well designed code.

Comment: It's a home screen...and as far as I've seen it seems its lifecycle is more complex than all the other activities. Have you ever developed an home screen?

Comment: We may disagree on what constitutes a lifecycle, but, in Android activities are supposed to be modular standalone entities, typically launched by anything that provides correct input parameters. By this train of thought home screen is just one activity and follows its lifecycle. Now it may be that we are talking about different things, in that case I wish you well in your search. Good Luck.