# How to show current task list pragmatically

Tags: java, android

I want to implement the functionality of **task switch button** (device hardware button) in my application. Can any one have any idea how to show the same task list pragmatically? ::

> **Note** I already know that there is a function from where you can get
>   current tasks and can show them but I don't want this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using [ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo.html)

ActivityManager has method getrunningtasks() and using that try to find a solution to your problem Activity manager seems to be the solution you are searching for.

```
  ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

for (int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); i++) {
    Log.d("Running task", "Running task: " + tasks.get(i).baseActivity.toShortString() + "\t\t ID: " + tasks.get(i).id);
}
```

also have a look at following thread  [See Android recent task executed by the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274874/see-android-recent-task-executed-by-the-user)

note:

The method getRunningTasks(int maxNum), [was deprecated in the API level 21(LOLLIPOP), for security reasons, the possibility of leaking personal information to third-party applications](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks(int)). (If you use this method to be aware that it will not be supported for future Android versions).

Comment: This is not my problem... I want to show the existing task list witch is already implemented in android.

Comment: current task n existing task both r different ? interesting !

Comment: No.. Both are same but i don't want to implement them myself. I want to send the message to some service which may show to task list.

Comment: Then you need to more clear in your question. anyways good luck folk :)